# Can we use Azure Functions as Web API?

Tags: azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on one notification application where we required mostly http trigger APIs and planning to use cosmos db for storage.

Can we go with Azure functions or should we use .NET Core Web API application?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your architecture.

If you are using more of a "dynamic" use case where functions will be called on-demand and you don't have the infrastructure or server with IIS on it, I would go with Azure Functions in the Serverless plan.

On the other hand if you're planning to create a VM, then using a .NET Core Web API application may be the best option for a more consisting environment where you can host not only your applications but other dependencies (e.g. databases) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could go with azure function, for the serverless API, you could integrate it with API management.

Reference - [Create an OpenAPI definition for a serverless API using Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition)

Answer (score 1):

You can, however if you have plans to host using consumption plan you should review how the price works. If you're expecting millions of requests it may not be the cheapest solution.

I still prefer to use functions to process something when an event happened rather than a replacement for web APIs (but this for enterprise apps).